# Which datatype is used to store large values?

Tags: android

I am the beginner of android application.Now i am reading large json values in the server and append these values to stringbuilder.The string builder only accept 3500 line of values.I have added extra values.I am getting out of memory error..Please Help me............

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, you're exceeding your allocation limit. I'm afraid you have no choice except dumping the response into a file (or secondary storage) or cleverly process the JSON partially and discard it once you do and make space for new data.